# Drop rows where a variable is nan for every year for each country in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a pandas dataframe that I have manipulated and it now is a panel. By that I mean I have a row for each country for each year and in each column there is a variable that I will use in a regression later. But I want to drop all rows where the variable "x" is equals to nan for each year for a specific country.

For example, rows 1 to 20 have the country "Andorra" (name in first column and year in second), with column "x" being nan for all years, so I want to drop all rows for "Andorra". I don't want to drop the country "Brazil" if it has at least one year with "x" different than nan (meaning I don't want to drop any rows for countries that have at least one "x").

I have tried to use loc and np.where but can't get that condition to drop only if all years are nan, I can only drop rows where "x" is nan, but if I do that I will end up reducing my sample way too much, seen that I will estimate "x" given I have at least a few years data for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```groupby``` is your friend. You can group by country / year, then remove multiple rows at once if at least one value is nan

Comment: But I need to remove multiple rows only if all values of x are nan for a group. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```py
for _, group in df.groupby(["Country"]):
    if group["Year"].isnull().all():
        df.drop(group.index, inplace=True)
```

using `gruopby` to group all rows with same `Country`. Then you iterate through the groups, and check if all values in `Year` is null using `isnull().all()`. If so, just drop the entire group.